# rvalue reference forwarding

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I am writing a wrapper around `std::jthread` and some surrounding infrastructure. I cannot wrap my head around why the following won't compile:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

// two random functions
void foo(int i) { std::cout << "foo " << i << std::endl; }

void bar(int i) { std::cout << "bar " << i << std::endl; }

// mechanism to identify them
enum function_kind {
    foo_kind, bar_kind
};
std::map<function_kind, std::function<void(
        int)>> kind_to_function{{foo_kind, foo},
                                {bar_kind, bar}};

// wrapper around jthread
// (additional functionality ommitted for brevity)
template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
class MyThread {
public:
    explicit MyThread(Callable &&function, Args &&...args) : m_thread{
            std::forward<Callable>(function),
            std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

private:
    std::jthread m_thread;
};

int main() {
    std::jthread t1(kind_to_function[foo_kind], 3); // works
    MyThread t2(kind_to_function[foo_kind], 3); // complains
    return 0;
}
```

I am really just trying to mimic whatever `std::jthread` is doing with my own class.

The IDE (clion) complains, that the first argument to `t2` is not an rvalue. The compiler complains a little more complicated:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:29:46: error: class template argument deduction failed:
   29 |     MyThread t2(kind_to_function[foo_kind], 3); // complains
      |                                              ^
main.cpp:29:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyThread(std::map<function_kind, std::function<void(int)> >::mapped_type&, int)’
main.cpp:20:14: note: candidate: ‘MyThread(Callable&&, Args&& ...)-> MyThread<Callable, Args> [with Callable = std::function<void(int)>; Args = {int}]’ (near match)
   20 |     explicit MyThread(Callable &&function, Args &&...args) : m_thread{std::forward<Callable>(function),
      |              ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:20:14: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:29:46: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘std::function<void(int)>&&’ to lvalue of type ‘std::map<function_kind, std::function<void(int)> >::mapped_type’ {aka ‘std::function<void(int)>’}
   29 |     MyThread t2(kind_to_function[foo_kind], 3); // complains
      |                                              ^
main.cpp:18:7: note: candidate: ‘template<class Callable, class ... Args> MyThread(MyThread<Callable, Args>)-> MyThread<Callable, Args>’
   18 | class MyThread {
      |       ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:18:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:29:46: note:   ‘std::function<void(int)>’ is not derived from ‘MyThread<Callable, Args>’
   29 |     MyThread t2(kind_to_function[foo_kind], 3); // complains
      |                                              ^
```

In any case, the arguments work for `std::jthread`, which also just takes rvalues... So what am I missing?

Comment: You can add CTAD for `MyThread` like `template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
explicit MyThread(Callable&&, Args&&...) -> MyThread<Callable, Args...>;`

Comment: That is a great use for trailing return types!

Comment: @Obay That is a deduction guide. It happens to look like a trailing return type, although that is not just by mere coincidence so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In any case, the arguments work for `std::jthread`, which also just takes rvalues... So what am I missing?

`jthread` is not a template, its *constructor* is a template. Which makes the rvalue references to template parameters into forwarding references, not plain rvalue references.

However, since `MyThread` is itself a template, and its constructor is not a template constructor, the behavior is not the same. After instantiation, it's a regular constructor that accepts only rvalues.

Forwarding references are contingent on template argument deduction happening for the function template they are a part of. So a non-template constructor means no forwarding references.

Okay, but you didn't specify template arguments to `MyThread`, why was there seemingly no error? Because class template argument deduction allows you to omit those. And CTAD happens in its own overload resolution step, completely disjoint from actually choosing a constructor to initialize the object. One step can be ill-formed while the other is not.

Answer (score 3):

The parameters of the `MyThread` constructor are not forwarding references because the constructor is not a template. Do not make the class a template, but only the constructor:

```
class MyThread {
public:
    template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
    explicit MyThread(Callable &&function, Args &&...args) :
        m_thread{
            std::forward<Callable>(function),
            std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

private:
    std::jthread m_thread;
};
```